# How to get multiple files base64 and each filenames via FileReaderAPI in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

> if I upload 3 items with the file name: png1, png2, png3  Result will
> be like this.
>
> alert 1
>
> png1 / base64 string convertion
>
> alert 2
>
> png2 / base64 string convertion
>
> alert 3
>
> png3 / base64 string convertion

I tried this code.

```js
    function readFile() {
        var input = document.getElementById('gallery-photo-add');
        var nameOfFile = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; ++i) {
            nameOfFile = input.files.item(i).name;
            if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.addEventListener("load", function (e) {
                    alert(nameOfFile);
                    alert(e.target.result);
                });
                reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
            }
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("gallery-photo-add").addEventListener("change", readFile);
```

```html
<input type="file" multiple id="gallery-photo-add" style="overflow: auto;">
```

Comment: thats just string manipulation - try the `+` operator.

Comment: @DanielA.White, Thanks for your response.
I change my question to be more specific of what output I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `+` operation to display filename and base64 toghther in one alert.

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators) is the reference to read more about JS operators

Edit: You want to alert and base64 togther which is not simple straight forward as base64 comes from `FileReader` API and filename is from `input`

I have wrapped your `base64` and alert in function and also have simplified the JS code your to call the function `onchange`

Working Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/usmanmunir/hpej8f6o/

Run snippet below to see it working.

```js
function readFile(input) {
  //Store file name
  var filesName = []
  //Get total files
  var filesTotal = input.files.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < filesTotal; ++i) {
    //Store file names
    filesName.push(input.files.item(i).name)
    var reader = new FileReader();
    //Display alert and base64
    function displayAlert(i) {
      reader.addEventListener("load", function(e) {
        alert(filesName[i] + ' Base64 ' + e.target.result);
      })
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
    //Display Alerts
    displayAlert(i)
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="file" multiple id="gallery-photo-add" onchange="readFile(this)" style="overflow: auto;">
```

Comment: @ClementBranzuelaGRANE I have updated my asnwer. Please check now. I have simplified your code as well.

Comment: @ClementBranzuelaGRANE Do not forget to accept my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and up-vote please thanks ;)